# connect to mysql database with php issue

Tags: php, android, mysql, server-error

I'm going to expand my local project  (that used mysql database and php ) to web.
i upload all file and changed all addresses to my server.

but my app wont work and i get the error like this in server Error log:

```
[10-Feb-2014 04:06:38 America/New_York] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20100525/magickwand.so' - /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20100525/magickwand.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
```

my app is load some list of goods. then it can be shown detail and edit.
there is no image.
what is this problem and how I can solve it?

Answer (score 0):

You don't have ImageMagick installed at your server.

Comment: I update the question and there is no image in app. plz check that. thanks. :)

Answer (score 0):

In order to use the MagickWand For PHP module's functions, you need to install ImageMagick version 6.3.5, or greater, and the MagickWand for PHP extension source code / DLL. For more detail please see here http://www.magickwand.org/

Comment: where this component needed in my code. may it's better to remove that part.

Comment: functions of this component is already included in your code. you should install this component(library) on your server.